# Worklight - MTOM attachments image file

Tags: android, ios, json, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

As part of my worklight project, we are calling a web service which sends the image file as an MTOM attachment. Is there a way where I can parse the image content and convert to JSON object? Below is a piece of code from my adapter where I configured the service call:

```
 var input = {      
 method : 'post',
 returnedContentType : 'plain',   
 path: '/contentaccess-ws/ContentAccessDocument_1',     
 body : {       
  content: retrieveDocumentRequest.toString(),      
  contentType : 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'   
  }
 };
```

And below is the response:

```
--MIMEBoundary_89c65bb62e242e7ee812d596799431326111505dc1baf518
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=utf-8;           
type="application/soap+xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0.99c65bb62e242e7ee812d596799431326111505dc1baf518@apache.org>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">  
<soapenv:Body><c:retrieveDocumentResponse xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis.open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:c="http://nationwide.com/schemas/Communication/iaa7_1/Content/DocumentManagement_1">
<c:Document><c:Attachments type="Content">
<c:Attachment><c:Name>Photo.jpg</c:Name>
<c:MimeType>image/jpeg</c:MimeType><c:Size>147623</c:Size>
<c:DataContent><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:a9c65bb62e242e7ee812d596799431326111505dc1baf518@apache.org"/></c:DataContent>
</c:Attachment></c:Attachments>
<c:Properties><c:Property><c:Name>Id</c:Name><c:Value>{D0C04F-0000-C511-983F-4BD2AB945534}</c:Value></c:Property><c:Property><c:Name>F_PAGES</c:Name><c:Value></c:Value></c:Property></c:Properties>
</c:Document><c:Status>Successful</c:Status>
</c:retrieveDocumentResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundary_89c65bb62e242e7ee812d596799431326111505dc1baf518
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <a9c65bb62e242e7ee812d596799431326111505dc1baf518@apache.org>

????_JFIF___HH??(ExifMM*__?i___??8Photoshop 3.08BIM__8BIM_%_?_?ُ?_? ???B~
___?_?__"______??_________________  
_???_____________}_______!1A__Qa_"q_2???_#B??_R??$3br?       
    ___%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz??????????????????????????????    ?????????????????????????????????????????????____________________ 
_???______________w______!1__AQ_aq_"2?__B????   #3R?_br?
_$4?%?     ____&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz?????????????????????????????????    ?????????????????????????????????????????C______ __ -   -=----      =M=====M]MMMMMM]]]]]]]]pppppp?????????????????C____%#%@##@?    hUh????????????????????????????????????????????????????_^??
```

I tried "returnedContentType" as "JSON" but no use (service throws me an error).

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The adapter won't do this for you.

What you need to do is to get the response from the adapter, and use whichever framework is able to decode the image attachment into a real image.

Normally MOTM is not used. Rather you base64 encode the image to a string and you then decode the string back into an image.

Comment: Manually parsed the response and able to get only the bottom portion of the response as a string. Did Base64.encodeBase64(data.getBytes()) and then converted it to String. USed the <img> tag to display the image. But still unable to display the image on the mobile devices.

Comment: It might be that the encoded string is just too long to be used.

Comment: oh ok. Is there any other way to get the image displayed?